# How can i simulate an UAV on Gazebo?

Tags: quadcopter, gazebo, simulation, uav, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all!
I need to create an UAV model for Gazebo, a Quadrotor. I need to control it also, by keyboard.
What can i do? There is some package that allow to do that?

Creating the model it's not so hard, but i don't know how to control it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12042/how-can-i-simulate-an-uav-on-gazebo?/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your best bet would be to look in the [AscTec Pelican](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/AscTec) stack. This quadrotor has a functional urdf file that can be used to bring up the pelican in Gazebo. I don't believe that the urdf provided functions 100% in Gazebo yet, so [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2168/pelican-model-in-gazebo) is a link to my previous resolution of this issue.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-05**:
I've still been unable to solve this problem. The one advantage is that with this configuration, you can create your own quadrotor mesh and load it in place of the pelican's mesh and it should still work.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-11-23**:
The .stl file is indeed incorrect in some way. I'm not exactly sure why/how this happened, but I reproduced your error exactly. The odd part is that it looks perfectly fine in Rviz. I'll look into this.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-19**:
You can also check out the hector quadrotor stack recently released. http://www.ros.org/news/2012/03/announcement-of-hector-quadrotor-stack.html documentation http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor